# Probability of going bankrupt on coin game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, game-theory, gambling

You play a game with a coin. You may place a bet; if Heads is flipped then you receive
your bet back plus the same in winnings. If Tails is flipped then you lose your bet.

You have \$10 and you want to turn this into \$100 by continuously betting \$1 at a time,
walking away when you either have a total of \$100 or are bankrupt. What is the probability
you will leave being bankrupt?

> My idea is to create a set of stochastic equations and solve for the probability that you go bankrupt. However, is there a more simple way to solve this quickly? This looks similar to the Gambler's ruin problem. (My intuition says 10%)

Comment: This is known as the [Gambler's Ruin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin) .  It isn't just similar to it, it is the same problem (with $n_1=10$ and $n_2=90$, to use wikipedia's notation).

Comment: Your intuition should say that with a fair coin and starting with less than half your target, you are more likely to go bankrupt first than reach your target.

Answer (score 0):

This is a one dimensional random walk, and we can move either -1 or +1 with the same probability in each step. We wish to compute the probability of reaching zero (-10 from the starting point) before reaching 100 (+90 from the starting point). This is known to be $$ \frac{10}{10+90} = \frac{1}{10}.$$

Comment: Except that $\frac{10}{10+90} = \frac{1}{10}$ is the probability of reaching $100$ first, and the question asked for the probability of reaching $0$ first.